# How to retrieve specific column from the dataset?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Here's the lines that are querying the database.

```
string sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5"
           + "FROM MyTable"
           + "WHERE condition";

DataSet standardResults = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
    m_ConnectionString,
    CommandType.Text,
    sql);
```

For each column, I'd like to select **col1** and **col5**.

I'm trying to hover over the dataset object or drill down the content, but I can't figure out where the data I need are located.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you need only col1 and col5, why do you select col2, col3 and col4

Comment: Because, it's an existing query, used by another feature. I just need those 2 columns to do what I have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you have posted, I can **assume** that the `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset` returns a `DataSet`. A `DataSet` contains a collection of `DataTables` and you can use a index to get them. In your case there would be only one `DataTable`, since you have the results of one query. So `standardResults.DataTables[0]` would be associated with the `DataTable` where your data are in. That being said, I think that you can fairly query your `DataTable` with LINQ and get that you want. Something like this:

```
var results = standardResults.DataTables[0]
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(item=>new 
                             {
                                Col1 = x.Field<string>("col1"),
                                Col5 = x.Field<string>("col5")    
                             });
```

However, I have to point out that I don't see the reason of selecting the extra columns, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`. If you don't need them, why they are in the select statement?

Comment: Christos method would do it great. just to clarify: .Select(item=>new 
                             {
                                  col1=item.col1,
                                  col5 =item.col5
                             });